# Winsock File Transfer in C

Tags: c, file, sockets, winsock, transfer

Does anyone know where I can find a website with a whole layout on how to program a file transfer program using sockets (Winsock) in C? Strictly C, so no C++ nor C#. I want to test out transferring files over from my desktop to my laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/), that's where I learned how to use socketing in C. It's mainly Linux-based but it does [include information on how to use it with Windows](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#windows). You simply have to `#include <winsock.h>` and call `WSAStartup`.

There are also a lot of comprehensive guides on the internet, along with simple client-server examples you can implement.